# SASS/SCSS - Hex Colors Mathematical Calculations

Tags: html, css, sass

This question is for learning purposes only. I understand the logic behind math operations in SASS when calculating hex colors, i.e.:

```
<div>Style me</div>

div {
color: #010203 + #010203;
}
```

I know it will be calculated in this way:

```
01 + 01 = 02
02 + 02 = 04
03 + 03 = 06
```

which will compile to: `color #020406;`.

More precisely:

```
div {
color: #020406;
}
```

How are hex colors calculated when you have letters in them? For example:

```
div {
color: #a1b1c1 + a2b2c2;
}
```

Are they calculated like this:

```
a1 + a2 = a3
b1 + b2 = b3
c1 + c2 = c3
```

which would compile to `color: #a3b3c3;` ?

If so, how would then

```
div {
color: #a1a2a3 + #b1b2b3;
}
```

calculate?

Would `a1 + b1` result `c2`?

If it would, what would happen with:

- multiplication `*`
- division `/`
- modulo `%`

I know this is a very long question and I apologize for that.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can try this and find out yourself, right?

Comment: `#ff0000 + #00ffff` = `#ffffff` (which makes quite sense but let's see further:) `#eeeeee + #eeeeee` = `#ffffff` which could make you conclude every HEX+HEX (R,G or B) channel that sums over 255 stays at 255. (`Min( R1_16 + R2_16, 255)`)

Comment: Thanks Roko. Post it as an answer please. 

@Mei, what is the purpose of this website if not to share knowledge? I can find out it by myself, true, but I hope this way someone else might learn as well, as I have noted in the question's first sentence. And by discussing with other people we can find our more, than by ourselves. I don't see how your comment helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example of `#010203 + #010203` you should first split the string to retrieve RGB channels, so than you can do RED+RED

```js
var R1   = parseInt("01", 16);      // 1
var R2   = parseInt("01", 16);      // 1
var R1R2 = Math.min(R1 + R2, 255);  // 2

console.log( R1R2.toString(16) );   // "2"
```

add a leading zero and here you go with `02`, repeat for all other channels and you got your `#020406`

Let's see another example with letters:

```js
var R1   = parseInt("9f", 16);      // 195
var R2   = parseInt("ae", 16);      // 174
var R1R2 = Math.min(R1 + R2, 255);  // 255  <<< !!!!!

console.log( R1R2.toString(16) );   // "ff"
```

so since R1 + R2 are exceeding 255 max value for RED channel, 255 will be used,
convert it back to HEX and you have `ff`.

**To conclude:**

`#ff0000 + #00ffff = #ffffff` which makes quite sense but let's see further:
 `#eeeeee + #eeeeee = #ffffff` which could make you conclude every HEX+HEX (R,G or B) channel that sums over 255 stays at 255. (pseudo-code:) `Min( R1_16 + R2_16, 255)`